# Parse body of POST reqest in self-made server in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, post, request, webserver

I am writing mock Ruby servers to test components of API. I send a POST request with a body, and I'd like my mock server to return a body of that POST request. Currently i have this code:

```
require 'socket'

webserver = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 7125)
loop do
  session = webserver.accept
  session.print "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\r\nContent-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
  request = session.gets
  session.puts request
  session.close
end
```

A POST request with body `FOO` returns a response with body that contains only `POST / HTTP/1.1` How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own HTTP server is really going to get you into trouble because the specification, while superficially simple, has a number of subtle nuances that can trip you up. In this case, you're reading one line with `gets` and ignoring the bulk of the submission. You're going to have to address that by reading in and properly decoding the posted data.

For something with a familiar interface you might start with [Net::HTTP::Server](https://github.com/postmodern/net-http-server) instead.